# When the mass flux is constant, why does $ v d\rho = - \rho dv$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, velocity, flow, density

I'm reading about mass fluxes and I came across when the mass flux is constant $$ j = \rho v$$ then the following equation is true $$ v d\rho = - \rho dv$$ What does that last equation even represent? I mean I understand that $\rho$ is density and $v$ is the velocity, but I don't understand it why it is true and what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Since $j$ is constant, $dj=\rho dv+ vd\rho=0$.  Any change in the density must be compensated by a change in velocity to keep the mass flow constant.

Comment: To make it more obvious, this is true by the product rule. Some first-timers are not used to seeing the product rule written only with differentials. :)